# Combustion/dispersment of mercury (Hg)

Tags: reaction-mechanism, thermodynamics

recently tuning a motorcycle using a manometer that contained liquid mercury.  Small amount probably a little more than a thermometer but not much more. Unfortunately the meter was upended and the mercury was sucked through the 4 vacumn ports on the motorcycle cylinders and cycled through the running engines combustion chambers and exhausted out of the exhaust system assumably in vapor form? The mercury did not go through the carburetor but was sucked into the cylinders through vacuum ports just after them but just before the intake valve. So it was directly sucked into the 4 cylinders.   Only a minute trace of mercury was found in one or two of the rubber hoses on the tool afterward. My concern short term was the obvious vapors from the accident but the garage area was mostly open with front and rear overheads open to the outdoors being a garage of course.

This brings me to the questions. After much research I found that Hg burns at 350f I believe but I can’t find any real information that pertains to a situation as this. Would the mercury burn completely into a vapor in the combustion chamber of an engine or would the extremely dense nature and slow evaporation rate effect the time frame that it takes as mixed with a fuel in this case to completely burn?  Do you think the mercury was completely burned and vaporized in the time it was in the combustion chambers of the motorcycle or did millions of tiny uncombusted liquid mercury droplets get spewed all over the rear area of the garage and are simply sitting around evaporating and presenting a dangerous situation?  Any insight on this would be extremely helpful. I have searched for signs of any physical mercury but have found none. I am concerned that if the liquid mercury wasn’t vaporized and exited as tiny liquid mercury droplets into the garage that it may be still there of course.  I spend many hours in this garage woodworking and rebuilding motorcycles etc with the doors closed. In the summer of course I open the doors but in the evenings and most of the week the garage is closed up. In the summer like now it gets very hot inside which I’m sure helps evaporate the mercury if there is any leftover but I am still concerned about how much may or may not have been burned. Thanks in advance, J

Comment: Mercury doesn't really "burn" as fuel would. The wording is confusing - burning (as in a reaction) or evaporation (just physical change)?

Comment: What can we say? Some is probably still in the motorcycle and some was probably expelled in the exhaust. You'd need very sophisticated equipment to detect the traces now.

Comment: “Burning” was in regard to the fact that the engine was running and the combustion process was actively happening.  Was just interested in knowing if there was a chance that it would combust and be turned to a vapor that would be evacuated by the normal process of the room being open to the outdoors etc. or if it just passed through in liquid form unchanged by the combustion process and then mostly just scattered around by being expelled through the exhaust.

Comment: I understand the principle that some may be both in the engine and some expelled. I was just looking for an educated answer about the combustion properties (if any) and the “odds” of a percentage being combusted into vapor. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Knowing it’s effect on aluminum I am hopeful that very little if any remains, seeing as how the entire engine block and many other parts are solid aluminum. Not a great mix unfortunately. The engine has been fun a few times and ridden roughly 100 miles so it appears to be unaffected as yet.

Comment: Mercury won't "combust" but under the conditions you describe it will vaporise. Whether this vapour is a problem inside your garage depends on several things. If it doesn't condense (and you might not notice if it does as the droplets will be very small) the vapour level will depend on the airflow through your garage. So leave the door open a day or so and it will all be gone. But if there are traces of liquid (even unseen) vapour will accumulate any time the air circulation isn't good. It might be worth a professional check of the vapour level.

Comment: Can you identify the manufacturer or other info on the manometer? I tried to find a mercury manometer on the internet to estimate how much mercury went into the engine, but could not find any. I can visualize an amount from about 2 to 10 mL, or 25 to 125 grams. Maybe I'm way off.

Comment: Does your motorcycle have a muffler or baffle?

Comment: The unit was made by Race Pro. I have requested info but haven’t received any yet. They sell a refill it also doesn’t specify a measurement.

Comment: Yes the motorcycle has a muffler system on it which includes the factory installed baffle system. Which I assume has collected a bit of the mercury as well. I have ridden the bike several times and have probably over 100 miles on it since the event so I’m sure the heat and flow of the hot exhaust gases has at least minimized if not evacuated the remaining bit in there?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF00342256

Their estimate is about 50% of the Hg emerges as elemental, the rest as various Hg(II) compounds.  That's for pretty high temperature flue gases, and it's unclear to me that your exhaust stream contains the assorted trace gases in a coal plant's exhaust with which the Hg reacts.  Nevertheless, I'd say 50% is a reasonable WAG for how much of your Hg exited as elemental.